# How to check if a day is a certain date in asp.net c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to check, if a rendered day in a webcalendar-element is X-mas Eve or the first of January or another date of a year and if so, colour that date differently.

So if the day rendered is the third Monday in May, colour it differently. If it is X-mas eve, colour it differently and so forth.

All ive found so far is how to extract the day to a specific date. But I would like to do kinda the opposite. Has anyone done that and can offer some tips?

Comment: What input do you have, and what part specifically are you having trouble with? Is it generating a list of holidays, looping over a list of dates, comparing dates, applying a CSS class to specific date cells or anything else?

Comment: What have you tried? If you're looking for "the first Monday in May" this should not be hard to find (tip: work out what day May 1st is and do the math...).

Comment: The problem was that I didnt really now to start. I knew that I had to compare dates and calculate but couldnt really find a good starting point. But Tim and Jon went in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "do kinda the opposite" but:

```
static IsThirdMondayInMay(DateTime date)
{
    // The first X in a month is always in the range [1, 8)
    // The second X in a month is always in the range [8, 15)
    // The third X in a month is always in the range [15, 22)
    return date.Month == 5 && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday &&
           date.Day >= 15 && date.Day < 22;
}

static IsChristmasEve(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Month == 12 && date.Day == 24;
}
```

Or more generally for the last:

```
static MonthDayMatches(DateTime date, int month, int day)
{
    return date.Month == month && date.Day == day;
}
```

then:

```
bool christmasEve = MonthDayMatches(date, 12, 24);
```

Comment: I think you pretty much got it. While I've only found how to find out whether 2008/09/21 is a Monday, I havent found how to do the opposite: Determine, whether the Tuesday that is being rendered is the 3rd Tuesday of May of the current year or something. But again, I think you pretty much nailed it. I'm gonna work form there and see how far I get with it. Thanx a million!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the ASP.NET [`Calendar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Then use the [`DayRender` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This has an argument `Day` with a property `Date` which is the `DateTime`. Now you can use this date to decide whether it is a special day or not.

```
void DayRender(Object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = e.Day.Date;  // here it is
    if(IsSpecialDay(date))  // your method to determine if a given date is a "special"-date
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gold;  // or use the Style property to use CSS
}
```